# Local variables IA32 Assembly using scanf

Tags: assembly

I am having a slight issue figuring this out for some reason. Have to convert a small C program to assembly. Basically a small main for input which is gets a value for the size of an array from the user, the elements of an array from the user, and then calls quicksort..

My issue is with the following code:

```
pushl    %ebp
movl     %esp, %ebp
pushl    %esi
pushl    %edi
/*allocate i, n to stack */
subl     $8, %esp
/* n is at -12(%ebp), i is at -16(%ebp) */
pushl    $string1
call     printf   #printf("enter size of array: ")
addl     $4, %esp
leal     -12(%ebp),%esi
pushl    %esi
pushl    $format
call     scanf    #scanf("%d", n)
addl     $8, %esp
pushl    %esi
pushl    $string2
call     printf
addl     $8, %esp
```

I understand that scanf needs the address of where it's going to store, my problem being is when I go to call printf again,

```
printf("enter %d variables" ,n)
```

it prints the address of %esi. I need it to display the actual variable (obviously), and I need to be able to use the variable as a limit for a for loop to get the variables in the array, but it keeps segfaulting on me, which is due to it using the address instead of the actual variable.

The rest I'm fine with, I just can't for whatever reason, figure this issue out.

Comment: Please show the part of your code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: The issue begins when, during a for loop, I try to access the array:

    movl    A(,%esi,4),%eax

Comment: There is no for loop on the code you posted. You also didn't post the printf that is printing the wrong value.

Comment: Reworking the for loop at the moment. I edited in the second printf call. The second call will give me either a 7 digit garbage value or 0, which is really twisting my noodle right now.

Comment: `scanf` takes the *address of a variable* (`&n`) as the argument, `printf` takes the variable itself (`n`), but you're passing `&n` to both. To move the actual value into `esi`, you should perform `movl -12(%ebp), %esi` after `scanf`. (And check `scanf`'s return value...)

Comment: Using 
    movl  -12(%ebp),%esi
still gives me a garbage value. Apologies for being thick, still sorting out learning this...

Comment: Your "pushl %esi" before the final call to sprintf is going to display the address of n, not the value. Change it to [%esi] or load the value from esi before pushing it.